# There is an error with using FBO in combination with WebGL in the three.js

Tags: three.js, shader, webgl, gltf, webgl2

This is the original question link address, if I need more detailed address, I can provide it

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/using-webgl2-in-three-js-transforming-feedback-an-error-occurs-fbo/53194
When he makes a mistake, I get the wrong data in the change feedback, all 0s

[image]

Comment: Please put all relevant information in the question. When (not if) the link goes bad, this question will lose all of its context.

Comment: @吉姆01How to close this issue, I've solved it

Comment: If you have found a solution, then post it as an answer and accept your own answer. Do not post only a link as an answer. You question is also still lacking details. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).